# Which one is the best either Cached nor Non-Cached Google BigQuery in C# application

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-dotnet-client

I have developed C# application that reads data from Google Big-query using .Net Client Library.

**Query:**

```
Select SUM(Salary), Count(Employee_ID) From Employee_Details
```

If i am using Non-Cached Query (JobConfig.UseCacheQuery=false) in Job Configuration then able to get the result in ~6 Seconds.

If i am using Cached Query (JobConfig.UseCacheQuery=true) in Job Configuration then able to get the same result in ~2 Seconds.

Which is the best way to use Google BigQuery whether Cached nor Non-Cached. (Cached Query Execution time is faster than Non-Cached once).

If there is any drop-backs are present in Cached Queries? Kindly Clarify this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run a BigQuery query twice in a row, the query cache will allow the second query invocation to simply return the same results that the first query already computed, without actually running the query again. You get your results faster, and you don't get charged for it.

The query cache is a simple way to prevent customers from overspending by repeating the same query, which sometimes happens in automated environments.

Query caching is on by default, and I would recommend leaving it enabled unless you have a specific reason to disable it. One reason you might disable caching is if you are doing performance testing and want to actually run the query to see how long it takes. But those scenarios are rare.

Read more here:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#querycaching